# How to create a template creator with moveable objects?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

Good day,

I am currently working on an automatic system that generates invoices with data that it receives from an API. I am currently doing this with Django (Python) to create some variation. Well, I want to create a system with which you can easily create templates for these invoices. You have seen these kinds of systems before. You can move blocks with items such as a logo or text wherever you want. Well I know that these templates are further stored as HTML. Only nowhere I can find clear information about how I can easily assemble such a system or how such a system works. Below I show a GIF of the system what I want. If anyone has any information on this I will be very happy if you can share that with me :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only nowhere I can find clear information about how I can easily assemble such a system

Yes, because making such a system is not an easy feat. You shouldn't do it yourself unless you know what you're doing and you are ready to deal with a lot of edge cases.

That being said, there are libraries that enable you to create such interfaces. One being https://interactjs.io/ (not affiliated with them). Then you need a WYSIWYG/Markdown editor that can be enabled on click as a tooltip. For example, https://www.tiny.cloud/

Then you need to find a way to save and load everything. Depending on the library you use, you might be able to get away saving and loading the HTML. However, it's more likely you'll need to implement a proprietary way of saving data. For example, using JSON or XML.

Best of luck!

Comment: Yep, cannot stress enough the importance of your first sentence. Very true.
Not to mention how difficult is to make it play nicely on mobile devices once you get tricked into using absolutely positioned elements...